# Error while importing table from mysql to hdfs using sqoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

i am running this import command to import E_INFO table from MySQL databases to HDFS using sqoop. the job is failing with below given error.

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/HADOOP_BANK_DATA_POC --username root --password xxxxxxx --table E_INFO`

however a blank file is getting created without any records in hdfs as E_INFO.
your help here is highly appreciated.

```
h-user@h-primary:~/sqoop-1.4.7/bin$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/HADOOP_BANK_DATA_POC --username root --password xxxxxxx --table E_INFO
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2366: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_USER: invalid variable name
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2461: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_OPTS: invalid variable name
2022-12-24 21:33:59,888 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2022-12-24 21:34:00,034 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
2022-12-24 21:34:00,355 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
2022-12-24 21:34:00,356 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2022-12-24 21:34:02,279 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `E_INFO` AS t LIMIT 1
2022-12-24 21:34:02,678 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `E_INFO` AS t LIMIT 1
2022-12-24 21:34:02,693 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop
Note: /tmp/sqoop-h-user/compile/e0e749532f0eaa6daaca522c9759658a/E_INFO.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2022-12-24 21:34:07,748 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-h-user/compile/e0e749532f0eaa6daaca522c9759658a/E_INFO.jar
2022-12-24 21:34:07,798 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
2022-12-24 21:34:07,798 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
2022-12-24 21:34:07,798 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
2022-12-24 21:34:07,798 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
2022-12-24 21:34:07,830 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of E_INFO
2022-12-24 21:34:07,833 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2022-12-24 21:34:08,191 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
2022-12-24 21:34:09,386 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
2022-12-24 21:34:09,626 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2022-12-24 21:34:10,080 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2022-12-24 21:34:10,080 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system started
2022-12-24 21:34:10,722 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
2022-12-24 21:34:10,793 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2022-12-24 21:34:11,333 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local377089840_0001
2022-12-24 21:34:11,334 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2022-12-24 21:34:12,059 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-h-user/mapred/local/job_local377089840_0001_7cb16b63-36d5-4781-94e7-4bd839e2ca49/libjars <- /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/bin/libjars/*
2022-12-24 21:34:12,098 WARN fs.FileUtil: Command 'ln -s /tmp/hadoop-h-user/mapred/local/job_local377089840_0001_7cb16b63-36d5-4781-94e7-4bd839e2ca49/libjars /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/bin/libjars/*' failed 1 with: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/bin/libjars/*': No such file or directory

2022-12-24 21:34:12,098 WARN mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Failed to create symlink: /tmp/hadoop-h-user/mapred/local/job_local377089840_0001_7cb16b63-36d5-4781-94e7-4bd839e2ca49/libjars <- /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/bin/libjars/*
2022-12-24 21:34:12,099 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/tmp/hadoop/mapred/staging/h-user377089840/.staging/job_local377089840_0001/libjars as file:/tmp/hadoop-h-user/mapred/local/job_local377089840_0001_7cb16b63-36d5-4781-94e7-4bd839e2ca49/libjars
2022-12-24 21:34:12,256 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2022-12-24 21:34:12,261 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
2022-12-24 21:34:12,264 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local377089840_0001
2022-12-24 21:34:12,352 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2022-12-24 21:34:12,353 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2022-12-24 21:34:12,362 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
2022-12-24 21:34:12,743 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
2022-12-24 21:34:12,745 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local377089840_0001_m_000000_0
2022-12-24 21:34:12,831 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2022-12-24 21:34:12,841 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2022-12-24 21:34:12,918 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2022-12-24 21:34:13,007 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
2022-12-24 21:34:13,012 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: 1=1 AND 1=1
2022-12-24 21:34:13,025 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
2022-12-24 21:34:13,134 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local377089840_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class E_INFO not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:552)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class E_INFO not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2638)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:527)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class E_INFO not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2542)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2636)
    ... 12 more
2022-12-24 21:34:13,345 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local377089840_0001 running in uber mode : false
2022-12-24 21:34:13,351 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2022-12-24 21:34:13,354 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local377089840_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2022-12-24 21:34:13,389 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
2022-12-24 21:34:13,396 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
2022-12-24 21:34:13,402 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 3.998 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
2022-12-24 21:34:13,404 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
2022-12-24 21:34:13,404 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
2022-12-24 21:34:13,404 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Import job failed!
```

Comment: Did a local E_INFO.java file get created? Why continue to try fighting Sqoop errors? It's not supposed to be this difficult, but it's also not maintained, so no one will ever fix it

Comment: Using sqoop just for time being, once my data is loaded in hdfs and other team is ready to fetch it. I ll then make the sqoop replacement in parallel.

Comment: But data doesn't need to be in HDFS, right? Other teams can use JDBC/ODBC to access th]e E_INFO table? Otherwise, use Spark [to read](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) and [to write](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#saving-to-persistent-tables)

Comment: Can you tell in which folder is can check if the E_INFO.java file is created or not?

Comment: It should be the folder that you ran the sqoop command from, if I remember correctly. _[A by-product of the import process is a generated Java class which can encapsulate one row of the imported table](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_prerequisites)_. Read the import section on how to control/override this behavior

Comment: Also, read error more closely, you have `ln: failed to create symbolic link`. That seems to be how it's attempting to load some JARs, and that's after some /tmp location mentioning `E_INFO.jar`

Comment: Yes the E_INFO.java file is getting created.